# Comparison of two long lists for every combination

Tags: python, string, list, similarity

I have two lists of 170000 elements each say list1 and list2 containing strings. The elements of the 2 are the same. I would like to confront the elements of list1 with all the elements of list2 and get a score of their similarity.

What I am trying to do at the moment is:

```
%%time
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

fuzzy_match = {}

lista1 = data_min.doc_std_name.to_list()
lista2 = data_min.doc_std_name.to_list()

for i in range(len(lista1)):
    for j in range(len(lista2)):
        fuzzy_match[lista1[i]+"_vs_"+lista2[j]]=fuzz.partial_ratio(lista1[i], lista2[j])
```

however this takes exponential time to run (I have tried with the first 10 elements it takes almost 140ms; with the first 100 4 seconds and with the first 1000 7 minutes).
Is there a way to perform the same task in linear time?

Thank you

Comment: If you are ok with a somewhat lower precision, you can randomly choose 1 thousand items from each list at the same indices and compare those, this will give you a good estimate of the similarity of the whole list (albeit with some noise)

Comment: Since `lista1` and `lista2` are the same, you can change the range for `j` to `range(i, len(lista2))` to halve the number of comparisons by scrapping duplicates. Furthermore, you can change `lista2` to `lista1` everywhere since you never alter the values.

Comment: Your stated need to compare every item in one list with every item in another list makes it  sound like there would be no shortcuts.  Obviously you could consider multi-threading on your local machine, or mapping the function in spark on a large compute cluster.  However if you explain your intended use for the output, perhaps someone could chime in with a better alternative.

Comment: @Chris could you please provide a code for multi-threading? Remmelzwaal thanks a lot for the reply!

Comment: @Lusian There are already a lot of great examples on this site of how to leverage multithreading.  Try looking up some of those answers and integrate those into your code.  If you get stuck please post another question with the details

Comment: @Lusian Exponential time? You mean *quadratic*?

Comment: @Chris Don't you mean multi*processing*?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your desired result dictionary will take at least 2 TB of memory. Do you have that much?

Comment: @KellyBundy no I have not. Actually I would like to keep only the elements whose strings show a similarity above a certain threshold and drop the others in the loop